# Debranding wp-admin with htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I don't like that WordPress sticks its branding everywhere, like with `http://example.com/wp-admin`. I would much prefer a debranded version like `http://example.com/admin`. Is this possible with a .htaccess rule? Is this a bad idea from a security and/or accessibility point of view?

Comment: May be this Thread can help you

http://serverfault.com/questions/281881/how-do-i-obscure-my-wordpress-install-via-htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [How to Hide The Fact That You’re Using WordPress | Ben Word](http://benword.com/how-to-hide-that-youre-using-wordpress/)

> • Cleaning up the output of wp_head and removing the generator from
>   RSS feeds
>
> • Hiding /wp-content/ by rewriting static theme assets (CSS, JS, and
>   images)
>
> • Cleaning up the output of navigation menus with a custom walker
>
> • Root relative URLs

Answer (score 3):

Follow the changes bellow:

#### .htacess code

```
RewriteRule ^secret-folder/(.*) wp-admin/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress-3.3/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress-3.3/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

#### wp-config.php

```
define('WP_ADMIN_DIR', 'secret-folder');
define( 'ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', SITECOOKIEPATH . WP_ADMIN_DIR);
```

#### themes/your_theme_name/functions.php

```
add_filter('site_url', 'wpadmin_filter', 10, 3);

function wpadmin_filter( $url, $path, $orig_scheme ) {
    $old = array( "/(wp-admin)/");
    $admin_dir = WP_ADMIN_DIR;
    $new = array($admin_dir);
    return preg_replace( $old, $new, $url, 1);
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'restrict_wp_admin');

function redirect_wp_admin(){
    $redirect_to = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if(count($_REQUEST)> 0 && array_key_exists('redirect_to', $_REQUEST)){
        $redirect_to = $_REQUEST['redirect_to'];
        $check_wp_admin = stristr($redirect_to, 'wp-admin');
        if($check_wp_admin){
            wp_safe_redirect( '404.php' );
        }
    }
}
```